# Kibana and the _source field, Elastic Version 6.7

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want a simple Pie chart based on my Index. However the fields in the result seem to be embedded within the *_source* field, which cannot be used in a *Terms* Aggregation in Kibana.
[image]

Sample Result is shown below:

[image]

Now if I disable the _source field in the mapping:

[image]

I don't get **any of the fields**:

[image]

However, the Kibana Discover page is listing the available fields, which are never returned by the ES results - when _source was enabled.

[image]

The Index Mapping is as shown below:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "filter_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "english"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "tags_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "filter_stemmer"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "schemav1": {
      "properties": {
      "user_id": {
            "type": "text"
        },

        "technician_query": {
          "analyzer": "tags_analyzer",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "staffer_queries": {
          "analyzer": "tags_analyzer",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "status":{
            "type":"text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The JSON document you send is stored int he `_source` field, that's normal. Are you sure you properly created your index pattern in Kibana?

Comment: The Kibana Discover page is listing the available fields, which are never returned by the ES results - when _source was enabled. Added screenshot above.

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your index please?

Comment: @Val Added Mapping.

Comment: Ok, and are you sure that your index pattern in Kibana is refreshed? What do you see there?

Comment: Yes, the index pattern is refreshed & showing all fields, as shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the reason is simple, in order for your fields to be used in aggregations, you need to have a `keyword` version of them. You cannot aggregate `text` fields.

Transform your mapping to this:

```
  "mappings": {
    "schemav1": {
      "properties": {
        "user_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },

        "technician_query": {
          "analyzer": "tags_analyzer",
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "staffer_queries": {
          "analyzer": "tags_analyzer",
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "status":{
            "type":"keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So, `user_id` and `status` are now `keyword` and `technician_query.raw` and `staffer_queries.raw` are also `keyword fields, which you can use in terms aggregations, hence in Pie charts as well.

Comment: Thanks Rock-star @Val!